# How to design a pipeline for creating users in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, pipeline

In Azure SQL DB, if we want to create users for the DB. Is there a way to create a pipeline instead of connecting to the Azure SQL Database server as an admin via SQL Server Management Studio or Azure Data Studio from on premises.